# sendmail is not able to send outbound mail

Tags: routing, sendmail, localhost

I have set up a server and need sendmail for my Icinga monitoring. I installed sendmail and played around with it. I am not able to send files to a gmail account.

My mail log is as follows:

```
Jul 11 16:23:46 li911-131 sendmail[12202]: u6BGNYO4012202: to=sethmschallau@gmail.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:12, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=30025, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (u6BGNjJ3012214 Mes$
Jul 11 16:23:46 li911-131 sendmail[12216]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
Jul 11 16:23:46 li911-131 sendmail[12216]: u6BGNjJ3012214: to=<sethmschallau@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<root@li911-131.members.linode.com> (0/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120346, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [IP$
Jul 11 16:23:46 li911-131 sendmail[12216]: u6BGNjJ3012214: u6BGNkJ3012216: DSN: Service unavailable
Jul 11 16:23:46 li911-131 sendmail[12216]: u6BGNkJ3012216: to=<root@li911-131.members.linode.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=31606, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

I know that the DSN: service unavailable means that Gmail is rejecting me, but why?

I have tried removing a line in the sendmail.mc file:

```
#DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')dnl
```

:

```
#127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
127.0.0.1 li911-131.members.linode.com li911-131
45.53.109.131   li911-131.members.linode.com li911-131
```

That is my /etc/hosts file, I have the first line commented out in an attempt to not send from 'localhost.localdomain'

I cannot figure out why I am not able to send outbound, any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"I didn't test it enough" -everyone

I had it in my answer, I am being rejected by Gmail, why though?

I'll tell you. It is because I have no [MX record](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/postini/docs/admin/en/activate/mx_faq.html) at all. I am not coming from a DNS server, but I can fix this by contacting Linode (the hosting service for this project). I will not bother as I do not need to send to anyone but my own exchange for the purposes of this project.

If you cannot send to Gmail and you DO need to then you will need a static IP and to contact your DNS provider to verify you.